# Exercise 6, Section 4.4 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, solution-verification, proof-writing, ideals

> Let $F$ be a field. Show that the ideal generated by a finite number of polynomials $f_1,\dots,f_n$ in $F[x]$ is the intersection of all ideals containing $f_1,\dots,f_n$

**My attempt:** Let $N= \{M\subseteq F[x]\ | \ M \text{ is ideal in }F[x]\text{ and }\{f_1,…,f_n\}\subseteq M\}$. We need to show $f_1F[x]+…+f_nF[x]=\bigcap N$. Suppose $f\in f_1F[x]+…+f_nF[x]$. Then $\exists g_1,…,g_n\in F[x]$ such that $f=f_1g_1+…+f_ng_n$. Let $M \text{ be an ideal in }F[x]\text{ and }\{f_1,…,f_n\}\subseteq M$. By definition of ideal in $F[x]$, we have $f_ig_i\in M$, $\forall i\in J_n$. Since $M$ is subspace of $F[x]$, we have $f_1g_1+…+f_ng_n\in M$. Since $M$ was arbitrary, $f_1g_1+…+f_ng_n\in M$, $\forall M\in N$. Thus $f_1F[x]+…+f_nF[x]\subseteq \bigcap N$. It’s easy to check, $\{f_1,…,f_n\}\subseteq f_1F[x]+…+f_nF[x]$. So $f_1F[x]+…+f_nF[x]\in N$. Thus $\bigcap N\subseteq f_1F[x]+…+f_nF[x]$. Hence $f_1F[x]+…+f_nF[x]=\bigcap N$. **Is my proof correct?**

Comment: Yep, this appears to be a flawless proof. Maybe as a random remark, there is a direct analogy to the span of a set of vectors as the set of all linear combinations of those vectors to being the intersection of all subspaces containing those vectors.

Comment: @EthanMartin nice remark! $\text{span}(S)=\bigcap \{W\subseteq V|\ W\text{ is subspace of } V\text{ and }S\subseteq W\}$.